# Update and insert MySQL using Classic ASP

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to update on a database in MySQL using Classic ASP, but it's not working. Could someone tell me what might be wrong in my code?

```
IDCliSession = Session("usuarioident")

if IDCliSession <> "" then
   IDCliSession = IDCliSession
else
    IDCliSession = 0
end if

set cli = conexao.execute("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = "& IDCliSession &"")

senha_S = request.form("senha")
senha_C = request.form("confsenha")
senha =  request.form("confsenha")

if senha1 & "" <> "" or senha2 & "" <> "" then
    if senha_S <> senha_C then
        response.redirect "Registro.asp?msg=A Senha e a Confirmação de Senha não são iguais. Por favor, preencha novamente!"
    end if
end if

loja = "1062"
tipoPe = request.Form("tipo")
email = request.Form("email")
fone1 = request.Form("fonefixo")
fone2 = request.Form("fonecel")
cep = request.Form("cep")
tipo_residencia = request.Form("tipo_residencia")
endereco = request.Form("endereco")
numero = request.Form("numero")
bairro = request.Form("bairro")
complemento = request.Form("complemento")
cidade = request.Form("cidade")
fk_estado = request.Form("estado")
fk_pais = request.Form("pais")
data = Date()

if request.Form("newsletter") = "1" then
    newsletter = 1
else 
    newsletter = 0
end if

conhecimento = request.Form("tipo")
modalidade = request.Form("modalidade")
modalidade_ativa = "0"
comentarios = ""

if not cli.eof then
    query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE email='"& Session("mail") &"'"
    Set rsCliente = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    rsCliente.Open query, conexao, 2, 3

    rsCliente("tipo") = tipoPe
    rsCliente("email") = email
    rsCliente("senha") = senha
    rsCliente("fone1") = fone1
    rsCliente("fone2") = fone2
    rsCliente("cep") = cep
    rsCliente("tipo_residencia") = tipo_residencia
    rsCliente("endereco") =endereco
    rsCliente("numero") = numero
    rsCliente("fk_pais") = fk_pais
    rsCliente("newsletter") = newsletter
    rsCliente("conhecimento") = conhecimento
    rsCliente("modalidade") =   modalidade

    rsCliente.Update

    rsCliente.Close
    Set rsCliente = Nothing
end if
```

Comment: Could you post your connection string?  Also, would you know if this code works with Microsoft databases (ie SQL Server or MS Access)?

Comment: @John They have said they are using `MySQL`. But seriously Rick, using `ADODB.RecordSet` to update, hugely inefficient. You could probably accomplish all of this in a [MySQL Stored Procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx) and use a `ADODB.Command` object to call it.

Comment: @Lankymart - the reason for my comment is that he's using a cursor type/lock type combination which I'm not sure would work with the MyODBC driver - especially not the older v3.51, and I can just imagine that code being copied from something which uses Access

Comment: @John Good point, just wasn't clear to me what you were asking from your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Besides inefficiency of the method you chooses, could you also look if the variables you attempt to update to actually not conflicting with database indexes or primary/foreign keys in database?
If you attempt to pass empty string into fields which set as not null it will abort procedure.

For example field tipoPe = request.Form("tipo") or email = request.Form("email") could be a mandatory in your table or set as unique. I do not see any validation for that...

Best solution would be use of a store procedure which would return you a string in case of failure or successes.
And also what are you attempt to validate her:

```
 senha_S = request.form("senha")
 senha_C = request.form("confsenha")
 senha =  request.form("confsenha")

 if **senha1** & "" <> "" or **senha2** & "" <> "" then
    if senha_S <> senha_C then
```

where does  **senha1** and **senha2** comes from?
For password verification following would be more then sufficient:

```
 if senha_S <> senha_C and len(senha_S)<8 then
```

using len(senha_S)<8 you also enforcing minimal lenght of the password.
Also I would recommend following changes in your redirect:

```
 response.redirect "Registro.asp?msg='A Senha e a Confirmação de Senha não são iguais. Por favor, preencha novamente!'"
```

otherwise you may on your redirect page get only small portion of your message, like only first letter A.